# How to format floating point value with fix number of digits?

Tags: c#, format, double, tostring

Is it possible in C# to format a double value with double.ToString in a way that I have always a fixed number of digits, no matter on which side of the decimal point?

Say I wish 6 digits, I want to have these results:

- 0.00123456789 gives "0.00123"
- 1.23456789 gives "1.23457"
- 123.456789 gives "123.457"
- 0.0000000123456789 gives "0.00000"
- 12345678.9 gives "12345679" (on overflow I want to see all digits left of decimalpoint)
- 4.2 gives "4.20000"

I'm experimenting with double.ToString, but cannot find any suitable format string.

Already tried "G6" (gives sometimes exponential format), "F6" (comes close, but 0.123456789 gives "0.123457" which are 7 digits).

Comment: The last one appears to be wrong. And what have you tried?  Some examples of format strings, pls.

Comment: What about a value like `4.2`, ? That doesn't have 6 digits to begin with.

Comment: otherwise you can do `string formattedOutput = string.Join("", number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Take(7));`

Comment: Its rather nonsense to show _trailing_ zeros like 0.0000 or  4.20000. The `g` formating does what is accepted as "good representation"

Comment: @DrKoch: it's a very technically oriented application where there are many numbers in columns and the users don't want to see the decimal point "jump" around when there are e.g. 4.12345 and 4.2 obove each other.

Comment: Because of your overflow case, your question is very misleading.  After all, you aren't trying to convert to a _fixed_ number of digits.

Comment: @Habib: I cannot find Take(), what is this?

Comment: @MTR, its from `System.Linq`, make sure you have `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @ryanyuyu: do you have a solution, if you ignore the overflow case?

Comment: @Habib: unfortunatly Take truncates without correct rounding.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of your examples are wrong. 
But I still think that I understand what you want to achieve.

I made an extension method.

```
public static class StringExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ToString(this double d, int numberOfDigits)
    {
        var result = "";

        // Split the number.
        // Delimiter can vary depending on locale, should consider this and not use "."
        string[] split = d.ToString().Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if(split[0].Count() >= numberOfDigits)
        {
            result = split[0].Substring(0, numberOfDigits);
        }
        else
        {
            result = split[0];
            result += ".";
            result += split[1];

            // Add padding.
            while(result.Count() < numberOfDigits +1)
                result += "0";

            result = result.Substring(0, numberOfDigits + 1);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I ran it with your examples:

```
        double d0 = 0.00123456789;
        double d1 = 1.23456789;
        double d2 = 123.456789;
        double d3 = 0.0000000123456789;
        double d4 = 12345678.9;
        double d5 = 4.2;

        Console.WriteLine(d0.ToString(6));
        Console.WriteLine(d1.ToString(6));
        Console.WriteLine(d2.ToString(6));
        Console.WriteLine(d3.ToString(6));
        Console.WriteLine(d4.ToString(6));
        Console.WriteLine(d5.ToString(6));
```

This is the output:

`0.00123
1.23456
123.456
1.23456
123456
4.20000`

I don't think this is the best way to solve it, but I like extension methods.

DoubleConverter class: http://1drv.ms/1yEbvL4

Comment: doesn't round correctly and d3 should give "0.00000"

Comment: It seems to have with how .NET rounds doubles. I did a quick search and found this: http://www.drawbackz.com/stack/25535/formatting-doubles-for-output-in-c.html

Comment: no, I it's because result.Substring doesn't round but truncates the string.

Comment: No, have you looked at what you get when you do .ToString on 0.0000000123456789d?
You get: "1.23456789E-08" because of the rounding of the double.

Comment: Sure. But Substring truncates this to "1.23456", correct would be "1.23457". There is no way to tell Substring to treat this string as a number and round correctly.

Comment: I followed through with that article I posted earlier and downloaded John Skeet's DoubleConverter and used that in my test. It now produces the correct result.

If you are having problem finding the class I uploaded it to OneDrive: http://1drv.ms/1yEbvL4

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to avoid "jumping" of the decimal point:

1. Use `g` formating, this does the most sensible thing to do
2. See where the decimal point is in your resulting string
3. pad with spaces at the beginning to *align* the column at the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, there is no predefined format that does what I need. So for everyone who is interested, here is the function I ended up with:

```
public string FormatValue(double d, int noOfDigits)
    {
        double abs = Math.Abs(d);
        int left = abs < 1 ? 1 : (int)(Math.Log10(abs) + 1);

        int usedDigits = 0;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(; usedDigits < left; usedDigits++)
        {
            sb.Append("0");
        }
        if(usedDigits < noOfDigits)
        {
            sb.Append(".");
            for(; usedDigits < noOfDigits; usedDigits++)
            {
                sb.Append("0");
            }
        }
        return d.ToString(sb.ToString());
    }
```