# How to specify number of digits for a decimal type with .ToString()

Tags: c#

I would like to specify that I want 6 digits when I convert a value from a decimal to a string. I have the following code.

```
decimal bound = (decimal) field.MaxVal; //trait.MaxVal is a Nullable decimal...
// my debugger shows that bound contains the value 20.0000000000
int numDigits = 6;
string num = numDigits.ToString();

string output = bound.ToString("G" + num);
// output is '20' i expected '20.0000'
return output;
```

Any ideas on how I would do this.

**I am focused on getting a total of 6 numbers in my string as opposed to 4 decimal places!**

**NOTE: bound will may have more or less than 2 digits in the whole number part.**

Comment: @HereticMonkey Not necessarily, I want to know if I can specify the number of digits I want in the number eg. for 20.0000, and numDigits=4 I should get 20.00

Comment: Looks more like [String.Format - How can I format to x digits (regardless of decimal place)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11789194/215552) or [How to format floating point value with fix number of digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28217098/215552) then.

Answer (score 2):

```
string output = bound.ToString("F" + num);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#FFormatString

F stands for fixed-point.

Comment: This helps but unfortunately is not what I need, I want to know if I can specify the number of digits for the number. eg. 20.0000, and numDigits=4 should give 20.00.

Comment: @Kikanye, can you clarify what is the expected behaviour if the integer part is longer than 6 digits? Do you want something like "F" + Math.Max(num - Math.Floor(Math.Log10(n) + 1), 0);